# How to abort broadcast notification? (for a non Ordered Broadcast)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, broadcast

My application deals with Cell Broadcast messages, which is a non ordered broadcast.
I want my application to receive this broadcast and kill the message notification of CB messages.

I've found out that SMS notification can be  suppressed by using an intent filter with a priority tag as shown below

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.sis.xxyyReceiver" >
      <intent-filter android:priority="999">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
         </action>
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So I've tried to do the same with CB messages like this

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED" >
     </action>
</intent-filter>
```

But it didn't work, and the log cat looks as follows

[image]

From my research and below comments, I've learned that non Ordered broadcasts cannot be aborted, So all I want to do is to suppress the notification (i.e CB_SMS alert and vibration) generated by CB message.

Can anyone help me with this aborting of non ordered broadcasts notification??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could turn down the volume?

Or maybe just emulate the bluetooth headset hook to autoanswer the call (silently)?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
                        new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

                Intent o = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                o.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
                        new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                context.sendOrderedBroadcast(o, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Comment: Do I need to use any permissions in my manifest for either of them to work?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot abort regular broadcasts. Everybody who has registered a `BraodcastReceiver` for them will get them.

Comment: Okay, can I hide the message notification alert for this non ordered broadcast? If yes, How can i do it?

Comment: @Code: "can I hide the message notification alert for this non ordered broadcast?" -- I do not know what the "message notification alert" is. If you mean the `Notification` that some other app displays, then no, you cannot hide it.

Comment: by "Message notification alert" I mean to refer to the notification alert generated by your phone when you receive a text message (Or CbMessage in this case)

Comment: @Code: In Android, that is a `Notification`, and you cannot hide other apps' `Notification` requests, any more than they can hide yours.

Comment: I know that is Notification, I mean to refer to the alert generated by Notifications (I.E CB message ringtone and Vibration). To make it precise, I want the CB message to be available in the inbox but I want the alert (Both ringtone and vibration) to silenced...

Comment: @CommonsWare Can we make the notification generated by CB silent?? I just don't want the user to hear the notification..

Comment: @suufang: Only by modifying the OS, AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't think we can do that without rooting the device ryt? Can you suggest any solution for my problem?

Comment: @suufang: My suggestion would be for you to ask your own StackOverflow question. The title of this question is "How to abort non Ordered Broadcast notofication?", which is no longer what you appear to be seeking. Asking your own question, with luck, will bring more focused attention to your specific area of interest.

Comment: @CommonsWare and suufang : I am also in search for a similar solution, yet no luck :\

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you advise me to change the question?? I've been working on this for almost 2 weeks now :(

Comment: @Code Pl make the question more specific, if I post a similar question it would be like spamming the community.